# Minimalistic lightweight SMTP application to send e-mails from external software running on Windows

Tags: windows, email, smtp

We've got this accounting SW called "Money S4" and the users want a quite simple thing - to send e-mails directly from the app. Unfortunatelly, when you try to do so the standard way:

[image]

You get the error that "*there is no e-mail application... you shall install one... and/or assign one via control panel -> default apps*"

[image]

The thing is I do **not want to install any full e-mail client like *Thunderbird* just to send e-mails**...

Question:

Any tips for a Windows **lightweight app which would just send e-mails** (SMTP with startTLS on 587)? It obviously must have some minimal GUI to be called from the accounting SW, and it must support attachments.

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Hmm, I haven't known about SW Recommendations... OK, try there, could you (any admin here) migrate it there? I know this might be done, I just do not have the privileges... Thank you @DavidPostill